# Turning Custom Ribbon Tab into Add-In

Tags: excel, vba, add-in, ribbon

I am trying to turn a custom ribbon button I made into an add-in that others can use for any worksheet in Excel. I followed this [StackExchange post on making a custom ribbon tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8850836/how-to-add-a-custom-ribbon-tab-using-vba) to make the ribbon button, and I have it successfully working within one workbook (one Excel Macro Enabled file).

How can I export the ribbon tab XML along with the VBA callback module so another user can use this in their Excel installation?

Thanks!

Comment: have you had a look at this? seems like it would suit your needs

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20764336/sharing-custom-macros-and-custom-excel-ribbon-with-others-via-sharepoint

Comment: @ballsy26 That might help, but I don't think I'd be using Sharepoint for distribution.

Comment: yep, but in terms of moving the macros to an .xlam and distributing that instead, alternatively you can convert everything to vb.net and make a VSTO add-in which people can install

Comment: @ballsy26 Ah, I see what you mean. I'll take another look, though dePatinkin might be right (I haven't had a chance to check).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to do it. The simplest one is to put your `.xlsm` file in a known start-up folder like `XLSTART`.

To find the folders' location, in Excel:

1. Go to `File > Options > Trust Center`
2. Click `Trust Center Settings...`
3. Go to `Trusted Locations`
4. Put your file in one of the listed `XLSTART` or `STARTUP` locations.

The locations look something like this `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Root\Office<XX>\XLSTART\` for the whole computer, or like `C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Excel\XLSTART\` for the user.

When you restart Excel the file should be loaded automatically.

**In addition**: Saving your file as a `.xlam` will also make it behave as an add-in, and will not show the worksheet. You can find some information about the file type choice here [Excel: Book or Addin](http://www.jkp-ads.com/Articles/DistributeMacro02.asp).